# Write to a notepad typing

Tags: python, text-files

Can anyone help me fix this code? Trying to get it to write to a notepad but it just opens the file then stops. Any help is appreciated.
(I also want it to be like its typing instead of just c&p)

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.Popen(['notepad', "helloworld.txt"])
f = open('helloworld.txt','w')
import sys
from time import sleep
words = "hi"
for char in words:
    sleep(0.5)
    f.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Always import libraries at the start of your code.

Comment: Always close any open files at the end of the program!

Comment: Notepad doesn't show you the contents of the file unless it is saved. And it only gets saved when you `f.close()`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that, when you **request that notepad be opened** in the second line of your code the file helloworld.txt does **not** exist.

I wrote *request that notepad be opened* because this takes time. Meanwhile, the rest of your code is proceeding. If you were to omit the `sleep` and the `import` statements then it would execute in a heartbeat, well ahead of the time it takes to start up notepad.

Assuming that you had closed the file helloworld.txt it would be available to notepad by the time it opened!

However, we usually don't depend on uncertain timing. (Trust me.)

We would create the file, then open it with notepad, more or less like this.

```
f = open('helloworld.txt','w')
words = "hi"
for char in words:
    f.write(char)
f.close()    

import subprocess as sp
sp.Popen(['notepad', "helloworld.txt"])
```

I must add that this is *not* the same as writing directly into notepad itself. If you're asking about that then please see [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or one of the other libraries mentioned on that page.

Comment: yeah that was pretty much what i was trying to do but i wanted to see if it could make the effect of typing, do you know if theres a way to do so?

Comment: That's what products like pywinauto do.

Answer (score 0):

This code will open a new instance of Notepad using the subprocess.Popen() method and open a file named "helloworld.txt" in it. Then, the code opens the file in write mode using the open() method and writes the string "hi" to the file character by character with a delay of 0.5 seconds between each character using the sleep() function. Finally, the code flushes the standard output buffer using sys.stdout.flush() to ensure that any printed text is displayed immediately rather than being buffered.

Overall, the code demonstrates how to use the subprocess module to open other programs from within a Python script and how to write text to a file character by character. However, it is worth noting that the delay of 0.5 seconds between each character may not be necessary or desirable in all cases. Additionally, the code does not close the file after writing to it, so it is a good practice to add f.close() at the end of the script to close the file.  maybe you can find the error in here